# Is it possible to upload a CSV to redshift and have it automatically run and export the saved queries?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I manually uploaded a CSV to S3 and then copied it into redshift and ran the queries. I want to build a website where you can enter data and have it automatically run the queries when the data is entered and show the results of the queries.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Redshift does not have Triggers. Therefore, it is not possible to 'trigger' an action when data is loaded into Redshift.

Instead, whatever process you use to load the data will also need to run the queries.

Comment: Yea that's what I have been reading but was hoping it was possible. Thanks so much!